# Remove Duplicate Vertices at Runtime in Unity

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine

In my Unity project I have a dynamic mesh system which needs to be heavily optimized. Currently I'm looking for an algorithm to optimize the meshes by removing duplicate vertices at runtime (the meshes are combined into one giant mesh). Removing duplicate faces that occupied the same space was fairly easy, since they can both safely be removed if they shared the same space within a threshold (because they won't be showing).

I'm having a bit more trouble with duplicate vertices, as they need to be removed in a certain way or the mesh is completely messed up. After my initial try at it, I got an array of `Vector3` objects that contain the vertices, and I was able to manipulate that to a certain extent. It seems that removing is only half of it though, as after looking more into mesh topology it seems I need to do more of a merge after removing the other one.

This is the part where I'm essentially stuck. Seemingly, I thought it would be fairly simple. Get all the triangles a vertex that needs to be removed is attached to and reassign the triangles to the vertex that stays. It isn't that easy in practice though.

First of all, is there an easier way? I'm very surprised Unity doesn't have a merge vertices script somewhere, or at least an example. Secondly, is there a better way, and how? I came across spatial hashing, however, I'm still stuck at the part where I somehow merge the vertices. Third of all, merging the actual vertices. How should I go about this in the most efficient way possible?

Comment: After Unity 4, in the Settings for Droid and iOS publishing they do have a generic checkbox called "optimize meshes". I don't know if it'll optimize to the degree you're talking about above. Are you optimizing vertices for mobile platforms to increase FPS, or for a web project/standalone? Just curious..

Comment: @AmitApollo The project is for desktop, and it's being used to construct meshes at runtime. Basically a level editor, if you will, but it is composed mostly of mesh based elements. I'm combining the meshes so removing faces (which is a lot easier than vertices) and vertices will result in a pretty big performance gain.

Comment: I'm not understanding how exactly you're getting duplicate vertices. Could you explain?

Comment: @Xerosigma Sure thing. As I said in a prior comment, users are going to be placing meshes down in a completely dynamic way. The meshes are then combined into one static mesh that can be viewed in 3D in real-time. I'm looking to optimize all the duplicate vertices/faces that the combined mesh will have. Picture two cubes smashed together by the user. When I optimize it, I will delete the two faces that aren't seen (i.e. the duplicate faces), but there are still duplicate vertices that will be around 0.01f in distance from each other. Detecting and merging these vertices is where I'm stumped.

Comment: @user81572 Not to add to the problem but you should be aware of how Unity handles [UVs and normals](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/228841/dynamically-combine-verticies-that-share-the-same.html) too.  Unity uses duplicate vertices along UV seams.  For example, add a Unity cube and you'll see it has 24 vertices, not 8.  [Here is a forum script](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/39110-Octree-subdivision-problem-solved) for creating an Octree, useful for decreasing duplicate search complexity.

Comment: @Jerdak Yes, I am aware of this. However the meshes will be textured later. The meshes have vertex coloring so that should work if done right. Really this is just a simplified modelling process. For now I'm worried more about the best possible optimization.

Comment: Interesting, im in the same boat at the moment trying to optimize mesh data I generated procedurally, my code isn't very good and needsa bit of work but maybe it can help you to help me so to speak ... http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/53234/how-to-optimise-mesh-data?noredirect=1#comment91629_53234

Answer (score 2):

Would using a HashSet be of use in this situation? For those that don't know, a HashSet is like a list, but is much much faster when searching for elements. Due to the nature of HashSets, they cannot store duplicates. Storing the vertices in a HashSet could mean that any duplicates are simply not added, taking little to no processing power.

I know this question is old, but I thought I would try my best to help anyone else looking for this answer - I'm not a programming expert at all, just figured that writing this couldn't hurt.